# Method Needed to Create Annotation Function for ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am creating a plot with multiple annotations, so I wrote a function to simplify that process.  The ggplot() below shows the laborious `annotate()` commands for one "Szarkowski".  Since I'm going to add multiple segments and text, I created the `af` function (also shown below).  However, I throw a "cannot add ggproto objects together" error when using the function.

*How do I create my annotation function properly?*

### Data

```
df<-structure(list(
  Department = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Architecture & Design", "Architecture & Design - Image Archive", 
    "Drawings & Prints", "Film", "Fluxus Collection", "Media and Performance", "Painting & Sculpture", "Photography"), class = "factor"), 
  Year = c(1970, 1967, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970), 
  Gender2 = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), 
  Nationality2 = c(" American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", 
                               " American ", " American ", " American "), 
  YearDate = structure(c(20491200, -74203200, -295041600, -295041600, -295041600, -295041600, 20491200, 20491200, 20491200, 20491200, 20491200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
  American = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("American", "Not American"), class = "factor")), row.names = 5600:5610, class = "data.frame")
```

### Here is my Annotation function:

```
af<-function(s_yr,e_yr,y_pos,lab){
  annotate(geom="point",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(s_yr,"-01-01"))), y=y_pos,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="point",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(e_yr,"-01-01"))), y=y_pos,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="segment",
       x=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(s_yr,"-01-01"))), 
       xend=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(e_yr,"-01-01"))),
       y=y_pos,yend=y_pos,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="text",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date(s_yr("-01-01"))), y=y_pos+20,color='black',size=3,label=lab)    }
```

### Here is my ggplot() command, with the annotation function commented out

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(YearDate,fill=Gender2))+geom_bar()+
  scale_fill_calc()+
  xlab("Date")+ylab("Count")+
  #Szarkowski annotation -- this hard coding works fine
  annotate(geom="point",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1962-01-01")), y=600,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="point",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1991-01-01")), y=600,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="segment",
           x=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1962-01-01")), 
           xend=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1991-01-01")),
       y=600,yend=600,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="text",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1978-01-01")), y=620,color='black',size=3,label="Szarkowski")+
  # cannot add `ggproto` objects together
  # af(1970,1990,777,"FakeLabel") +   # this line throws an error; how to fix `af` function?
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Instead of `+`'ing the annotations together, try putting them all in a list. The list method for `+`'ing to a ggplot2 adds every element of the list to a plot. E.g., in `af()` do `list(annotate(...), annotate(...), ...)`.

Comment: Are you aware of an example you could share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RE: comments

Here is what I mean exactly. Remove all the `+`es from the `af()` function and instead put all the annotations in a list. Putting components in a list does not only work for annotations, but can be convenient for recycling any number of plot components for multiple plots. This is due to the `ggplot2:::ggplot_add.list()` method that implicitly `+` es all the list elements to the plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df<-structure(list(
  Department = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Architecture & Design", "Architecture & Design - Image Archive", 
    "Drawings & Prints", "Film", "Fluxus Collection", "Media and Performance", "Painting & Sculpture", "Photography"), class = "factor"), 
  Year = c(1970, 1967, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970), 
  Gender2 = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), 
  Nationality2 = c(" American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", " American ", 
                               " American ", " American ", " American "), 
  YearDate = structure(c(20491200, -74203200, -295041600, -295041600, -295041600, -295041600, 20491200, 20491200, 20491200, 20491200, 20491200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
  American = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("American", "Not American"), class = "factor")), row.names = 5600:5610, class = "data.frame")

af<-function(s_yr,e_yr,y_pos,lab) {
  list(annotate(geom="point",
                x=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(s_yr,"-01-01"))), 
                y=y_pos,color='black',size=1),
       annotate(geom="point",
                x=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(e_yr,"-01-01"))), 
                y=y_pos,color='black',size=1),
       annotate(geom="segment",
                x=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(s_yr,"-01-01"))), 
                xend=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(e_yr,"-01-01"))),
                y=y_pos,yend=y_pos,color='black',size=1),
       annotate(geom="text",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date(paste0(s_yr, "-01-01"))), 
                y=y_pos+20,color='black',size=3,label=lab)   
  )
}

ggplot(df, aes(YearDate,fill=Gender2))+geom_bar()+
  # scale_fill_calc()+
  xlab("Date")+ylab("Count")+
  #Szarkowski annotation -- this hard coding works fine
  annotate(geom="point",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1962-01-01")), y=600,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="point",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1991-01-01")), y=600,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="segment",
           x=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1962-01-01")), 
           xend=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1991-01-01")),
           y=600,yend=600,color='black',size=1)+
  annotate(geom="text",x=as.POSIXct( as.Date("1978-01-01")), y=620,color='black',size=3,label="Szarkowski")+
  # cannot add `ggproto` objects together
  af(1970,1990,777,"FakeLabel") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Teunbrand, please suggest a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/q/68948902/2884859

Comment: Hi AnilGoyal, I don't see how the linked question is related to this questions or my answer. Can you clarify why I should suggest a solution there for other reasons than that the question is so far unanswered?

Comment: No that's not related. I just wanted to tag you, you being subject expert