# Why my code for using png logos in axis labels in ggtext is not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, ggtext

I am trying to learn 'Improving Visualisations in R' presently following [this fabulous post](https://jcarroll.com.au/2021/07/02/improving-a-visualization/).

For the first part it seems working greatly.  But the part where axis text is replaced by logos is not working.  The error displayed is -

```
Error in png::readPNG(get_file(path), native = TRUE) : 
  file is not in PNG format
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

For this [blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/08/ggtext-for-images-as-x-axis-labels/) it is again throwing same error (i.e. `file is not in PNG format`)

Full `reprex` is as below (upto the part where it stops working)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(tools)


streaming <- tibble::tribble(
  ~service, ~`2020`, ~`2021`,
  "netflix",    29, 20,
  "prime",      21, 16,
  "hulu",       16, 13,
  "disney",     12, 11,
  "apple",       4,  5,
  "peacock",     0,  5,
  "hbo",         3, 12,
  "paramount",   2,  3,
  "other",      13, 15,
)

## pivot to long format with the 
## year and share as their own columns
streaming_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(streaming, 
                                      cols = -service, 
                                      names_to = "year", 
                                      values_to = "share")

## plot the years side-by-side in the original order
p <- ggplot(streaming_long) + 
  geom_col(aes(factor(service, levels = streaming$service), 
               share, fill = year), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
  ## add a hidden set of points to make the legend circles easily
  geom_point(aes(x = service, y = -10, color = year, fill = year), size = 4) + 
  ## add the percentages just above each bar
  geom_text(aes(service, share + 1, label = paste0(share, "%"), group = year),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 3) +
  ## use similar colours to the original
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(`2020` = "red3", `2021` = "black")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(`2020` = "red3", `2021` = "black")) + 
  ## hide the fill legend and make the color legend horizontal
  guides(fill = "none", color = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1), 
                     limits = c(0, 35)) +
  labs(title = "US Streaming Market Share", 
       subtitle = "2020 vs 2021", 
       caption = "Source: Ampere Analytics via The Wrap
       
       Other Streatming Services include ESPN+, Showtime,
       Sling TV, Youtube TV, and Starz",
       x = "", y = "") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 28, hjust= 0.5), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 28, hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 7, color = "grey60"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f4f7fc", size = 0),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text= element_text(size = 12),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        ## move the color legend to an inset 
        legend.position = c(0.85, 0.8)) 
p
#> Warning: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Create a folder `images` in working directory

```r
wiki <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/"
logos <- tibble::tribble(
  ~service, ~logo,
  "netflix", paste0(wiki, "0/08/Netflix_2015_logo.svg/340px-Netflix_2015_logo.svg.png"),
  "prime", paste0(wiki, "1/11/Amazon_Prime_Video_logo.svg/450px-Amazon_Prime_Video_logo.svg.png"),
  "hulu", paste0(wiki, "e/e4/Hulu_Logo.svg/440px-Hulu_Logo.svg.png"),
  "disney", paste0(wiki, "3/3e/Disney%2B_logo.svg/320px-Disney%2B_logo.svg.png"),
  "apple",  paste0(wiki, "2/28/Apple_TV_Plus_Logo.svg/500px-Apple_TV_Plus_Logo.svg.png"),
  "peacock", paste0(wiki, "d/d3/NBCUniversal_Peacock_Logo.svg/440px-NBCUniversal_Peacock_Logo.svg.png"),
  "hbo", paste0(wiki, "d/de/HBO_logo.svg/440px-HBO_logo.svg.png"),
  "paramount", paste0(wiki, "a/a5/Paramount_Plus.svg/440px-Paramount_Plus.svg.png"),
  "other", "other.png"
) %>% 
  mutate(path = file.path("images", paste(service, tools::file_ext(logo), sep = ".")))
labels <- setNames(paste0("<img src='", logos$path, "' width='35' />"), logos$service)
labels[["other"]] <- "other<br />streaming<br />services"

for (r in 1:8) {
  download.file(logos$logo[r], logos$path[r])
}
#> Error in download.file(logos$logo[r], logos$path[r]): cannot open destfile 'images/netflix.png', reason 'No such file or directory'



p <- p + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
p
#> Warning: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Error in png::readPNG(get_file(path), native = TRUE): unable to open images/netflix.png
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

On the code suggested by [Teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68953652/2884859), the following error is returned

```
> for (r in 1:8) {
+   download.file(logos$logo[r], logos$path[r], method = "curl")
+ }
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
Error in download.file(logos$logo[r], logos$path[r], method = "curl") : 
  'curl' call had nonzero exit status
```

Comment: Your code works fine. The issue is that something went wrong when downloading the logos as `#> Error in download.file(logos$logo[r], logos$path[r]): cannot open destfile 'images/netflix.png', reason 'No such file or directory'
` is telling you. From my own experience I would guess that there is no folder "images" in your working directory.

Comment: @stefan, thanks for comments.  I tried even after creating a folder images in my working directory.  Still it is not working.  showing the error as stated in question.  Just wondering is it windows/mac issue of escape character?? Not sure how to check that too

Comment: Hi Anil Goyal. Looks indeed like a Mac/Windows issue. your code works fine on my Mac but not my windows machine. I just had an idea. And it worked. Try with adding `method="curl"` to download.file.

Comment: Thanks @stefan, Even I manually downloaded the png logos in specified directly.  Even then it is showing this error `Error in png::readPNG(get_file(path), native = TRUE) : 
  file is not in PNG format`

Comment: Hm. Weird. Have you already tried to open one of the png outside of R? When I tried to open one of the pngs downloaded without method="curl" I got an error that this file type is not supported. But with method="curl" everything works fine.

Comment: So how can I see that which method is being used here?  By the way, the files downloaded were not opening.  But I also manually downloaded the correct files, placed them in specified folder, still it is not working.  How can I ensure method = curl is used here

Comment: Hm. I'm afraid that I'm at my wit's end when even manually downloading did not work. Maybe someone else has an idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: No issues.  Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me. To highlight a few changes:

- I changed the path for the downloads destination to `tempdir()` instead.
- I changed this line: `labels[["other"]] <- "other<br>streaming<br>services"`
- I added the `method = "curl"` in the `download.file()` function.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(tools)


streaming <- tibble::tribble(
  ~service, ~`2020`, ~`2021`,
  "netflix",    29, 20,
  "prime",      21, 16,
  "hulu",       16, 13,
  "disney",     12, 11,
  "apple",       4,  5,
  "peacock",     0,  5,
  "hbo",         3, 12,
  "paramount",   2,  3,
  "other",      13, 15,
)

## pivot to long format with the 
## year and share as their own columns
streaming_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(streaming, 
                                      cols = -service, 
                                      names_to = "year", 
                                      values_to = "share")

## plot the years side-by-side in the original order
p <- ggplot(streaming_long) + 
  geom_col(aes(factor(service, levels = streaming$service), 
               share, fill = year), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
  ## add a hidden set of points to make the legend circles easily
  geom_point(aes(x = service, y = -10, color = year, fill = year), size = 4) + 
  ## add the percentages just above each bar
  geom_text(aes(service, share + 1, label = paste0(share, "%"), group = year),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 3) +
  ## use similar colours to the original
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(`2020` = "red3", `2021` = "black")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(`2020` = "red3", `2021` = "black")) + 
  ## hide the fill legend and make the color legend horizontal
  guides(fill = "none", color = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1), 
                     limits = c(0, 35)) +
  labs(title = "US Streaming Market Share", 
       subtitle = "2020 vs 2021", 
       caption = "Source: Ampere Analytics via The Wrap
       
       Other Streatming Services include ESPN+, Showtime,
       Sling TV, Youtube TV, and Starz",
       x = "", y = "") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 28, hjust= 0.5), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 28, hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 7, color = "grey60"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f4f7fc", size = 0),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text= element_text(size = 12),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        ## move the color legend to an inset 
        legend.position = c(0.85, 0.8)) 

tmpdir <- tempdir()
wiki <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/"
logos <- tibble::tribble(
  ~service, ~logo,
  "netflix", paste0(wiki, "0/08/Netflix_2015_logo.svg/340px-Netflix_2015_logo.svg.png"),
  "prime", paste0(wiki, "1/11/Amazon_Prime_Video_logo.svg/450px-Amazon_Prime_Video_logo.svg.png"),
  "hulu", paste0(wiki, "e/e4/Hulu_Logo.svg/440px-Hulu_Logo.svg.png"),
  "disney", paste0(wiki, "3/3e/Disney%2B_logo.svg/320px-Disney%2B_logo.svg.png"),
  "apple",  paste0(wiki, "2/28/Apple_TV_Plus_Logo.svg/500px-Apple_TV_Plus_Logo.svg.png"),
  "peacock", paste0(wiki, "d/d3/NBCUniversal_Peacock_Logo.svg/440px-NBCUniversal_Peacock_Logo.svg.png"),
  "hbo", paste0(wiki, "d/de/HBO_logo.svg/440px-HBO_logo.svg.png"),
  "paramount", paste0(wiki, "a/a5/Paramount_Plus.svg/440px-Paramount_Plus.svg.png"),
  "other", "other.png"
) %>% 
  mutate(path = file.path(tmpdir, paste(service, tools::file_ext(logo), sep = ".")))
labels <- setNames(paste0("<img src='", logos$path, "' width='35' />"), logos$service)
labels[["other"]] <- "other<br>streaming<br>services"

for (r in 1:8) {
  download.file(logos$logo[r], logos$path[r], method = "curl")
}

p + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
#> Warning: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

This was done with R 4.0.5 on Windows 10 with ggplot2 v3.3.5 and ggtext v0.1.1.

Comment: May be I am missing something.  I tried this on another computer also.  Running everything fine up to `labels` creation.  After than download part gave this error `Error in download.file(logos$logo[r], logos$path[r], method = "curl") : 
  'curl' call had nonzero exit status`

Comment: Thanks.  Blocking the Kaspersky and using curl solved the issue